# Powershell call to start Chrome is opening Edge two out of three times

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell file that contains the lines:

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome","http://some/path/1")
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome","http://some/path/2")
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome","http://some/path/3")
```

... and every single time I run it, path1 opens in Chrome and the latter two open in Edge.

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                  
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                  
     40       5      844       3792       0.02  56748   1 chrome                                                                                       
     31       4      684       4020       0.02 106324   1 msedge                                                                                       
     31       4      684       4016       0.02  73624   1 msedge
```

What is going on?

Comment: Do you get the same results using `Start-Process`? I can assume so, just curious.

Comment: Is msedge the default browser? (not that it should matter...) What does the command look like for the main edge process? `gcim win32_process|? Name -Like 'msedge.exe'|select commandline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple URLs to chrome, try this:

```
[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome","http://some/path/1 http://some/path/2 http://some/path/3")
```

(But this will open in new tabs on the same window)

Comment: Thanks, so it turned out I was being an idiot and my second two calls were actually `::Start("http://..")` -- I missed out the "chrome", so they were being opened in the default browser which was Edge. Your answer helped me spot that.